Can a oracle TM for a language in $\Delta^0_{n+1}$ use two oracles for languages in $\Sigma^0_{n}$?
For reference, I am using Kozen's Automata and Computability, Lecture J. I am trying to prove that $\Delta^0_n = \Sigma^0_n \cap \Pi^0_n$.
In this book, I understood that Kozen defines $\Delta^0_{n+1}$ as the set of languages decidable with an oracle in $\Sigma^0_{n+1}$. To prove that a language $L \in \Sigma^0_n \cap \Pi^0_n$ is in $\Delta^0_n$ we are trying to build a decider for $L$ that uses both the oracle in the recognizer for $L$ and the oracle in the recognizer for $\overline{L}$. Is this possible by the definition $\Delta^0_{n+1}$? I.e. using two oracles goes against the definition?

You can define a single oracle whose even bits represent your first oracle and odd bits represent your second, and show this oracle is $\Sigma_n^0$ and usable for your purposes.
